Checking all possible combinations of integers with a fixed sum and size
I am trying to iterate over all possible combinations of integers with a given sum and size, in order to find the item with the lowest standard deviation.
For example, if sum=4 and the size=2 then these are all the possible combinations of integers:

[4,0], [3,1], [2,2], [1,3], [0,4]

I already have a recursive method in which 'remainingFacilities' is the sum and 'numberOfTransformers' is the size, and where all 'allPossibleFacilityCombinations' should contain all possible combinations:
private ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> allPossibleFacilityCombinations = new ArrayList<>();;

private void distributeFacilities(int remainingFacilities, int numberOfTransformers,
        ArrayList<Integer> facilitiesPerTransformer, int currentIndex) {
    if (currentIndex == numberOfTransformers) {
        if (remainingFacilities == 0) {
            // Create a new ArrayList based on facilitiesPerTransformer
            ArrayList<Integer> copy = new ArrayList<>(facilitiesPerTransformer);
            allPossibleFacilityCombinations.add(copy);
        }
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= remainingFacilities; i++) {
        facilitiesPerTransformer.add(i);
        distributeFacilities(remainingFacilities - i, numberOfTransformers, facilitiesPerTransformer,
                currentIndex + 1);
        facilitiesPerTransformer.remove(facilitiesPerTransformer.size() - 1);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //some code where I get totalNumberOfFacilities and numberOfTransformers

    ArrayList<Integer> facilitiesPerTransformer = new ArrayList<>();
    mainInstance.distributeFacilities(remainingFacilities, numberOfTransformers, facilitiesPerTransformer, 0);
}

The problem with this method is it runs out of memory if the number of possible combinations is too large. I specifically need these inputs to work:

totalNumberOfFacilities: 213
numberOfTransformers: 6

In this case the total possible number of collections is 3917788308. The method runs out of memory before it even gets 1% of the results.
How can I find the optimum combination without running out of memory?

What error message do you get when it crashes?

Hi I get usually something about memory heap. Though often I get no error and the progress just stops (I track the method's progress)

Nearly 4 billon combinations is going to use a large amount of memory - so you are running out of memory or the garbage collector is desparately trying to find more memory. But in any case an ArrayList is indexed by an int and can't hold that many entries anyway. This does not seem to be a sensible thing to be doing.

Please, note that the result (3917788308) exceeds int, that's why you should use long or even BigInteger

What you've given as an example are permutations, not combinations.

@DmitryBychenko where? The number 3917788308 represents the size of an arraylist

@KonstantinMakarov so the issue is just that I'm storing all the values in 'allPossibleFacilityCombinations'?

@KonstantinMakarov No I do not need all the permutations at once. The end goal is just to find the correct permutation out of all the possible ones, which would be the one having the lowest standard deviation among the currents passing through the transformers

so the problem is not really "finds all possible combinations", the question should be edited to include that additional information

@user85421 yes but I need to check all possible combinations to know which is the correct one since the calculation of the currents of the transformers is very long and complex so I can't just guess "if this combination's currents have a higher standard deviation than the previous combination then I can discard all those x combinations"

quoting myself: "the question should be edited to include that additional information', that means, it should not be added (only) as comment

Are you sure the total number of possible combinations is 3917788308? My solution reports 3917788288

The OutOfMemory issue occurs because you are trying to store all the combinations in a list, before evaluating them. Instead, you should first generate partitions (combinations of addends that have a common sum). of the 'totalNumberOfFacilities' value. For each of those partitions generate all the permutations of it. For each permutation, immediatly evaluate it's fitness, and keep track of the best candidate only. This will eliminate the need to store partitions and/or permutations in a list.
There is a neat (recursive) algorithm (source, credits) to partition a number.
To find the distinct permutations efficiently you can use 'Pandita's algorithm' which keeps the characters in lexicographical order.
I also included an algorithm to find the standard deviation, although I am not sure this is exactly the evaluation function you mean, since the end result seems rather trivial.
The solution below does not store any of the partitions or permutations, but uses the visitor pattern to visit each value in turn. This avoids any memory issues.
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.Consumer;    

public class FixedSumPermutations {

    private PermutationProcessor processor;
    private long partitionCount;
    private long permutationCount;

    private class PermutationProcessor implements Consumer<int[]> {

        private double bestScore;
        private String bestPermutation;

        @Override
        public void accept(int[] permutation) {
            double standardDeviation = calculateStandardDeviation(permutation);
            if (bestPermutation == null || standardDeviation < bestScore) {
                bestScore = standardDeviation;
                bestPermutation = Arrays.toString(permutation);
                System.out.printf("\rpartitions:%s permutations:%s %s", partitionCount, permutationCount, this);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("bestPermutation:%s standardDeviation:%s", bestPermutation, bestScore);
        }

        public double calculateStandardDeviation(int[] array) {

            double sum = 0.0;
            for (int i : array) {
                sum += i;
            }

            int length = array.length;
            double mean = sum / length;

            double standardDeviation = 0.0;
            for (double num : array) {
                standardDeviation += Math.pow(num - mean, 2);
            }

            return Math.sqrt(standardDeviation / length);
        }

    }

    private void findPartitions(int targetSum, int size) {

        processor = new PermutationProcessor();
        partitionCount = 0;
        permutationCount = 0;

        findPartitions(size, targetSum, targetSum, new ArrayList<>());
    }

    private void findPartitions(int positions, int remaining, int max, List<Integer> result) {
        if (remaining == 0) {
            List<Integer> partition = new ArrayList<>(result);
            while (partition.size() < positions) {
                partition.add(0, 0);
            }
            partitionCount++;
            findPermutations(partition);
            return;
        }
        if (result.size() == positions) {
            return;
        }
        for (int i = Math.min(max, remaining); i >= 1; i--) {
            List<Integer> next = new ArrayList<>(result);
            next.add(i);
            findPartitions(positions, remaining - i, i, next);
        }
    }

    private void findPermutations(List<Integer> value) {
        int[] permutation = value.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).toArray();
        Arrays.sort(permutation);
        int changePos;
        do {
            processor.accept(permutation);
            permutationCount++;
            changePos = walkDown(permutation.length - 2, permutation);

            if (changePos >= 0) {

                int swapPos = walkUp(changePos + 1, permutation, changePos);

                swap(permutation, changePos, swapPos);
                for (int i = changePos + 1, j = permutation.length - 1; i < j; ++i, --j) {
                    swap(permutation, i, j);
                }
            }
        } while (changePos >= 0);
    }

    private int walkUp(int swapPos, int[] chars, int changePos) {
        while (swapPos + 1 < chars.length && chars[swapPos + 1] > chars[changePos]) {
            ++swapPos;
        }
        return swapPos;
    }

    private int walkDown(int changePos, int[] chars) {
        while (changePos >= 0 && chars[changePos] >= chars[changePos + 1]) {
            --changePos;
        }
        return changePos;
    }

    private void swap(int[] chars, int changePos, int swapPos) {
        Integer temp = chars[changePos];
        chars[changePos] = chars[swapPos];
        chars[swapPos] = temp;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        FixedSumPermutations partitions = new FixedSumPermutations();
        partitions.findPartitions(213, 6);
    }
}

Output:
partitions:6444809 permutations:3917788288 bestPermutation:[35, 35, 35, 36, 36, 36] standardDeviation:0.5 

Thanks to Konstantin Makarov for pointing out that we are looking for integers, not digits.

Hi sorry I don't understand. The number of transformers can be anything.

The value I picked (24) is just an example. The idea is similar to what Lajos Arpad tried to explain. Instead of iterating over the whole range of numbers, you can first determine which collections of digits (partitions) fulfil your sum requirement. As you see above, there are only three partitions of 24 digits with sum 213. Now you only need to permutate the partitions to generate all your possibilities.

The question was about memory overflow, so that's the main issue we need to address. Your answer presents a way to optimize upon performance, yet, it does not explain how and why this answer would reduce memory use while storing  all the information we need in order to infer all the possible variations. So I think you will need to explain whether 1 2 3 and 3 2 1 are both to be stored. If not, then which one will be stored, how this is achieved and how can the full information be inferred back from your compression. When finished with the explanation, please ping me here so I can upvote

My solution does not store the permutations at all, only the partitions needed to generate the permutations. And even that could be avoided, if memory usage were still an issue (but it is not for the given query)

@AdriaanKoster, now I see the solution that I wanted to implement myself, but I never found the time to do it. I deleted my answer and voted for yours. And I also don't understand why such a good question has a negative rating. OP can delete this question along with your wonderful findPermutations function.

Adriaan memory usage is the issue, see "The problem with this method is it runs out of memory if the number of possible combinations is too large.". While performance improvement is also nice, the actual problem is out-of-memory. So you need to address this problem inside your answer so it will address the question. If you reread the question, you will see that it was not about performance.

@LajosArpad, Adriaan edited the code.

@KonstantinMakarov that's cool. But the answer needs to address the question and explain how it solves the out-of-memory problem. Adriaan already explained it in the comment-section, but we need that to be inside the answer.

@LajosArpad, inside the answer is the example of calling the accept function. You can change the code so that the delegate function is called, but these are details.

@KonstantinMakarov an answer needs to mainly address the problem raised by the question. In our case the answer focuses on performance improvement, which was not the worry of the question. Nevertheless, the answer's ideas are good and I would be happy to upvote, but in order to do so, the answer at least needs to explicitly address the problem raised by the question, which is out of memory. It should explain (that is, text inside the answer, with plain words and arguments) memory improvement. Beginners will not understand the code and will have no clue why it solves the out of memory prob.

The issue is mainly related to memory use. So, if you have many combinations, then as long as the number of transformers is n, then you have n! separate elements containing the different variations of the same combination.
So, if you have a combination of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 as a correct answer to some input, for example, then you store the 6 numbers 6! = 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 * 6 = 720. This is a huge waste. Instead you should only need to store the 6 elements and know that all permutations of these elements are correct solutions.
So, when you go through all your combinations:

check whether it's fulfilling your criteria
if so, normalize it (order the values)
check whether this normalized variation is already stored
if not, store it

This will largely improve upon your memory use. You can further improve upon it if you store your normalized combinations as tree branches, so you avoid repeating even the first elements from the combination. Yet, this will only be needed if the first optimization is not saving you enough memory.

Hi, thanks for the response. I have to go through each and every possible combination to find the correct one since the calculation that has to be done on each possible combination is very large and complex. There is no way to guess which combination would be getting closer to the correct one.

@HDNW you seem to assume that I was telling you that some combinations need not to be processed. Yet, I did not say anything like that. I merely said that you do not need to store all variations separately. You can store only the normalized form, which will not prevent you from parsing all the permutations of your combination. You will likely need to store the best combination so far so you will be able to compare your current combination with, but quite frankly it does not make sense to store separately every single permutation of a combination.

@HDNW it's a waste of memory to do so. Instead, store a single permutation of a combination with the knowledge of all the other permutations of the same combination are also valid. This is a way to compress data without data loss. You can unpack each combination into their permutations to loop and parse them, but you will win a lot of memory storage if you compress data like this. If the number of items in a combination is 6, then you store 720x smaller space.

@HDNW also, you can optimize performance too. For each element, start your cycle from the previous dimension + 1, so if you already have 1 as the first element, start your loop from 2. You will not miss anything this way, because if you found 1 2 3 4 5 6, then you have also found the other 719 permutations involving these numbers, so you can just parse them instead of searching for 2 1 3 4 5 6, for example.

I have noticed this answer has been down-voted, yet, I believe it's correct. If someone would point out what's wrong with it, then I would be happy to edit/delete this answer if needed.

I think it's because the answer is incomplete. You are focusing only on the memory usage and offering a correct improvement, but you missed the idea of partitioning the totalNumberOfFacilities first, and then permuting each partition. Also the permuting should be done lexicographically to avoid duplicates. BTW I gave you an upvote to get you out of the red. :-)

@AdriaanKoster thanks for your comment. Indeed, partitioning the number and finding all possible combinations and storing the results in a compressed manner (for example storing 2 4 6, but not physically storing the other permutations of this combination, since if a variation is correct, then all variations are correct involving the same elements) sounds like a good idea and could greatly contribute to performance optimization as long as it is implemented using an effective algorithm, the question was focused on memory overflow issues, so my answer was also focusing on that topic.

@AdriaanKoster normalizing a combination into lexicographic order is a possible solution for normalizing it and indeed I would choose that approach for normalization in order to avoid duplicates, however, in my answer I did not assume the normalization to rely on lexicographic order, because some projects might need a different kind of normalization for reasons I cannot foresee here. So all I was specifying in the answer was that we need to normalize (3rd point) by ordering the elements in some manner and then avoid duplicates (4th point) so I think this part was covered by the answer.
